# Save a C program output to a textfile

Tags: c, linux, terminal

Can anyone please inform me, how to save output of a C program to a text file without distorting the indentations?
I have tried using ">" and using the "logsave" command but in both case the indentations of output changes. I have tried manipulating the output by using tabspaces and whitespaces but still the problem remains. Is there a way that the output is saved correctly?
Output:

```
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +
Cache       |      L1D              |      L1D              |
Size        |      32K              |      32K              |
OScpu#      |        0        1     |        2        3     |
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +

Cache       |      L1I              |      L1I              |
Size        |      32K              |      32K              |
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +

Cache       |       L2              |       L2              |
Size        |     256K              |     256K              |
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +

Cache       |       L3                              |   
Size        |       3M                              |   
            +   ------  ------- ------- -------     +
```

is the output coming on the terminal and when saved to the text file it changes to :

```
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +   
Cache       |      L1D              |      L1D              |   
Size        |   32K             |   32K             |   
OScpu#      |       0        1      |       2        3      |   
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +   

Cache       |      L1I          |      L1I          |   
Size        |   32K             |   32K             |   
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +   

Cache       |       L2              |       L2              |   
Size        |  256K             |  256K             |   
            +   ------  -------     +   ------  -------     +   

Cache       |       L3                              |   
Size        |    3M                             |
            +   ------  ------- ------- -------     +
```

Comment: What is that C program exactly? Tell us more about it. And show some part of the output...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch have done the necessary edit

Comment: How are you printing it to the terminal and to the text file?

Comment: It looks like caused by mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Show also some `printf` used to produce the output.

Comment: yes it is a case of mixed tabs and white spaces. This is output of a C program - topo.c. On terminal the output is coming by simply ./topo.c and i am saving it by using:  ./topo.c > topo.txt.
I had tried the logsave command also, but with the same effect.

Comment: I can`t write the printf part as it is too lengthy and involves call of functions.

Comment: @sol did you try to save your output in your code instead of running it and then saving to a file ?????

Comment: I did not try it earlier, but it worked after i save the output directly to the file. Thanks.
But for knowledge sake, is there a way to do what I asked without directly saving in the code ?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert all tabs in the output of your program to spaces.

Try this:

```
./prog | expand > log-file
```